# Android different screen sizes and AVD

Tags: android

I'd like to implement several layouts: one for phone, another - tablet. This means I need to create a few folders: layout-normal, layout-large. Next, in order to test mechanism I need to somehow force avd to launch machine with specific width and height parameters (inches ?) - how is it done ?

Comment: you can create different emulators for different devices

Comment: yeah, but I'm a bit confused about it. What is the measure for width/height parameter ? I don't see anything regarding "size" in the manager - could you explain ?

Comment: refer this [May it helpful for you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678970/which-layout-is-suitable-for-all-android-mobile

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the machines display height / width / dpi when you create a virtual device in AVD Manager.

[image]

Comment: great, I must be missing something. Same size can have different resolutions - right?

Comment: Since the display is measured in pixels, size is irrelevant. And yes, different sizes may have same resolutions.

Comment: Why? My guess is that, in theory, there can be a device with small physical size and high resolution and vise versa. So in case of small physical size, high resolution I'm supposed to give user a phone layout, not a tablet one disregarding resolution values. Similarly in case of big tablet with low resolution I should still present tablet-oriented layout. So, why should I judge by resolution ?

Comment: imho, I dont think you'd have much luck finding the screen size. You could look into koneX's answer, he has provided a very good link, which you must go through if you are intending to target multiple sized screens. I personally had found it extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Edit: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438926/android-layout-large-folder-is-been-ignored) too, for setting a layout-large AVD

Comment: I've been struggling through it for the last couple of hours, yet it's  not clear what is the measure for physical height in terms of Android. Is it inch ? Or like Aki says - dp ?

Comment: Check out 'Table 3' in that link. When you are creating an AVD set the resolution in function of what you need (QVGA works for layout-small, HVGA works for layout-medium, etc)

Comment: Well, it seems to be something I've been searching for. I'll  study attentively and ask/accept a bit later. Thanks.

Comment: *Sighs* So, the measure for height/width is inch or dp ? Still puzzled about creating a custom device. Isn't it about specifying physical inches(size) and amount of device pixels(resolution) ?